# Android - Can you 'auto create' layouts while app is running?

Tags: java, android, list, scrollview

I'm trying to create a scrollabe friends list. I'm grabbing the information for each friend off of a text file (profile pic, name, age, etc.)

So in my prototype I used different nested layouts to create one single friend entry. And to fill the list I just copied the most parent layout of my first friend and changed or adjusted the profile pic and the other text information.

What if, while the app is running, I need to update my friendslist and add another friend to the list.

How do you realise something like that?

Comment: I highly recommend looking over the fundamentals of Android. This is in no way trying to be rude, it is to save you from the headache of trying to dive in without a solid foundation. This should be handled with a RecyclerView that uses an Adapter to make things dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for a recycler view or a scrollable list view to make a list and dynamic. You can check slidenerd's video tutorial on youtube. They are really helpful for a beginner to start any kind of app.